# Swift 3: Back gesture

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uipangesturerecognizer

I have in my Swift 3 application a homeViewController containing a `UITableView`. When a cell of the table is clicked, then I display a `detailViewController`. I display it as a child using the `addChildViewController(vc)`. I want to implement the back gesture in order to return to the homeViewController. I want to have the same result as the back mode in the default Mail application of the devices (the back mode to return to the mail's home when I was in the inbox for example). In other words, the gesture allows the user to drag the view from left to right then continuing the left to right drag until the home view is showed, or drag the view from right to left in order to keep the detail view in the whole screen. I tried to do that using the `UIPanGestureRecognizer` but my view goes left and right and sometimes its show the home view from the right side. So in brief, the result that I want is the same as the back gesture functionality of the Mail application.

This is my code:

```
    var rightSwipe: UIPanGestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer()
        self.rightSwipe = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleSwipes(_:)))
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(rightSwipe)
 func handleSwipes(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer){

        if self.rightSwipe.state == .began || self.rightSwipe.state == .changed {

            let translation = rightSwipe.translation(in: self.view)
            // note: 'view' is optional and need to be unwrapped
            //print("translation is : \(translation)")
            if(translation.x > 0 && translation.y == 0.0){
            self.rightSwipe.view!.center = CGPoint(x: self.rightSwipe.view!.center.x + translation.x, y: self.rightSwipe.view!.center.y + translation.y)
            rightSwipe.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self.view)
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: If you want that behaviour then simply push your ViewController in navigation stack.

Comment: Can you explain more please?

Comment: I tested 'self.navigationController.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)' instead of the addChild but when I click on a cell the detailViewController doesn't appear. Is that because my homeViewController is an UIViewController?

Comment: Have you embeded NavigationController with HomeViewController in your storyboard.

Comment: I have just do it now

Comment: Try once and it will work

Comment: No result. I can't see my detailViewController when I click a cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use `NavigationController` in your storyboard embeded your `HomeViewController` with `UINavigationController`. To embed navigationController select your `HomeViewController`, in menu choose `Editor > Embed In > Navigation Controller`.

Now in `didSelectRowAt indexPath` push the `detailViewController`.

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(detailVC, animated: true)
```

If still gesture is not work then in `HomeViewController`'s `viewDidLoad` set this one.

```
self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.isEnabled = true
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129230/discussion-on-answer-by-nirav-d-swift-3-back-gesture).